# how to dispaly image in jpanel by clicking on jbutton in jframe

Tags: java, netbeans-7

i want to know how to display image in jpanel by clicking on jbutton in jframe.

i created jpanel on jframe and added a button on jframe to display image in jpanel,

what code i want to add in jbuttonActionPerformed{ },

Comment: Show some if your tries and let us know what has not worked.

Comment: Put a `JLabel` in the panel, then call `label.setIcon(ImageIcon)` on the button press. If you don't know how to use `ImageIcon` for `JLabels`, do a search. There are hundreds of questions/answers here.

Answer (score 0):

you can load your image using Jfilechooser or you can put your image path directly.In here photo is a JLable.This should work.

```
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG, GIF, and BMP Images", "jpg", "gif", "bmp");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            file = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();

            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(file);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            img = img.getScaledInstance(photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), img.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);
            photo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            jInternalFrame1.setContentPane(photo);
```